# Passing parameters from WPF application to another WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, parameters

I have two applications developed in WPF(c#) which are independent on each other. Suppose Project A and B. they are developed separately.  i have connected those projects with the Button in project A, on click of that button i am starting project B with `Process.start();`

now i need to pass String (login) parameter to the another application (B) so user dont need to login again.
I have already seen the Command line argument passing but i dont want to use them.
also `Application.Current.Properties["parameterStringID"]` is not useful because i have different app.config for A and B

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: why not use command line arguments? works perfect.

Comment: @NahumLitvin : Thanks for help! may be command line will work but i want to know is there any other way to do this?

Comment: _but i dont think that will work for me._  Can you explain why you think so?

Comment: @lomed : now Ok my friend. i dont want to use them. sorry but i cant explain that why that will not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send commandline arguments to your application like this.

```
var applicationPath = "Path to application B exe";
var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(applicationExePath);
process.Arguments = "/login=abc /password=def";
process.Start();
```

And in your ApplicationB start, handle commandline arguments.

Comment: as i said in question they might not work for me.(consider as Special case). :( Sorry bro i wana know another way. thanks for help!

Comment: another method is through sending windows messages, or may be use WCF service,

Comment: i need to create another application for that one? like WCF service application or Widows service application.

Comment: You can create another application as well. But you can also use your current applications to host service in itself. You can make a P2P application.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms751502.aspx this is a sample chat client. In which applications talk to each other. You can use this reference and implement the same thing in your application.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this in the past by using either anonymous or named pipes, .NET has quite good support for them. There are [a few good articles about them on the MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762927%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for help! Do you have its example code. So i can better understand. can you please post it?

Comment: If you look at the child articles in the link I posted you'll see they have [full source code for both server and client side](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

do all your applications have similar login method?

make a AviCompany Login  `windows service` .
the service will be also a `WCF service` that provides method "Login"

see my chart

https://www.lucidchart.com/documents/view/410f-6e48-52c16052-a63b-4a5e0a009f85

Comment: yes my applications having similar login service(WCF). i got your point. but calling Login service again needs the login parameters.  what about them?

Comment: make another function.
call it `IsUserLoggedIn`.
call it before calling `Login`