# Passing parameters from one app to the other

Tags: c#, infopath

Following on from this thread [Starting application before target application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22556060/starting-application-before-target-application/22556644#22556644)

I have an application which gets passed a parameter (a filename) and does some registry work before opening Microsoft InfoPath.

I need to open InfoPath with the parameter that was passed to the original application.

Here is how I open InfoPath

```
System.Diagnostics.Process prc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
prc.StartInfo.Arguments = ConvertArrayToString(Constants.Arguments);
//prc.StartInfo.Arguments = "hello";
prc.StartInfo.FileName = Constants.PathToInfoPath;
prc.Start();
```

Note that when I set the Arguments to "hello" InfoPath pops up a message saying cannot find file "hello" however when I set it Constants.Arguments I get an error and Windows asks me if I want to debug or close the applicatiion.

Here is how I set `Constants.Arguments` in the `Main(string[] args)`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Constants.Arguments = args;
    //...
}
```

And here is `ConvertArrayToString`

```
private string ConvertArrayToString(string[] arr)
{

    string rtn = "";
    foreach (string s in arr)
    {
        rtn += s;
    }

    return rtn;

}
```

I suppose the format of the parameter is causing the error, any idea why?

The value of `Arguments` after being stringed is

```
c:\users\accountname\Desktop\HSE-000403.xml
```

Edit:

Thanks to N K's answer.

The issue is in order for my application to open when InfoPath files are opened, I have changed the name of INFOPATH.EXE to INFOPATH0.EXE and my application is called INFOPATH.EXE and is in the InfoPath folder, so when files are opened my application opens.

Now when I do not change the name (eg I leave it as INFOPATH.EXE) it works as expected, however if it is called anything other than that then I get the error.

Unfortunately I need my application to open first.

Comment: I tagged it as c# and the language does affect how parameters are passed.

Comment: you might need this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838440/passing-parameters-from-wpf-application-to-another-wpf-application

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Jason see last line of question, I am using full path.

Comment: humpty - no error just the Windows has encountered an error (nothing specific)

Comment: ConvertArrayToString vs string.Join

Comment: NK no difference, end result is the same.

Comment: @andrewb, I just suggest a better way, not the answer to your question. Sorry.

Comment: @andrewb Sure, it's important to include a proper language tag, but among tags, not in a title if not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the below and it's works fine. Let me know what you get with this. (Don't forget to change path to files)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process prc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        prc.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Join("", Constants.Arguments);
        prc.StartInfo.FileName = Constants.PathToInfoPath;
        prc.Start();
    }
}
public class Constants
{
    public static string PathToInfoPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\INFOPATH.EXE";
    public static string[] Arguments = new string[] { @"c:\users\accountname\Desktop\HSE-000403.xml" };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, see my edit. Basically because I modify INFOPATH.exe filename it throws an error.

Comment: In the end I just created a sub folder, stuck the "real" executable in there and started that process. While this answer did not solve my issue it is "correct"

Comment: "I just created a sub folder, stuck the "real" executable in there", it might have dependencies, so putting in to separate folder might break the dependency.